# How to get current page URL in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-9

I'm trying to output the current page URL on a Drupal site (Drupal 7), I've tried the following...

```
<?php print current_path(); ?>
```

Which outputs the page name but not the URL, any ideas on how to output the full URL too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In straight PHP you can use this:

```
$curPathName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$currentURL = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
```

I don't see why that wouldn't work.  That will give you the path and the URL.

Comment: I've opted for <?php print $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . current_path(); ?> which seems to work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you could accept the answer then, since that is what I suggested. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<?php 
    global $base_url;
    print $base_url . '/' . current_path(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep things done "the drupal way", you can use current_path() or request_path().

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_path/7

You can also use $base_url instead of relying on $_SERVER.

The solution durbpoisn gave will give you the URL in the browser.  If that is an alias, you can use drupal_get_normal_path() to get the internal path

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_normal_path/7

Answer (score 1):

in drupal9

```
$current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
$path_alias = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

On D7 if you want to get the current path you can use:

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias();
```

So if your current URL is:

[www.test.com/hello/world](http://www.test.com/hello/world)

You will get:

'hello/world'